# lazily convert a String with words to a Stream of words

Tags: scala

Given a string with words and whitespaces such as "aaa bbb ccc ddd", can you lazily convert this to a stream that splits the string by white space such as Stream("aaa", ???)? Is creating an iterator first required?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a javish solution, but may suit your needs. You can utilize the fact that java.util.Scanner is also an Iterator (though, it's a java iterator)

```
import java.util.Scanner
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val str = "aaa bbb ccc ddd"
val tokenizer = new Scanner(str).useDelimiter(" ")
// this will trigger conversion from java Iterator to Scala one,
// can be written in more explicit way
val it: Iterator[String] = tokenizer
// it: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator
val stream = it.toStream
// scala.collection.immutable.Stream[String] = Stream(aaa, ?)
```

Above code can be written as nearly one-liner:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import java.util.Scanner

val stream = new Scanner(str).useDelimiter(" ").asScala.toStream
```

Comment: "this will trigger conversion from java Iterator to Scala one" really? `JavaConverters._` is used, so `asScala` call is needed to perform the conversion (just like in your last example).

Comment: @VladimirMatveev sure, I had JavaConversions in scope so I confused them

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that should work after looking at the scaladocs. In order to mimic string's `split(regex: String, limit: Int)` function, edge cases will need to be handled separately such as 1 and 0.

```
  def wordStream(s: String): Stream[String] = {
    def loop(offset: Int): Stream[String] = {
      val substring = s.substring(offset)
      val preWhitespace = substring.takeWhile(_.isWhitespace).size
      val word = s.substring(preWhitespace).takeWhile(c => !c.isWhitespace)

      word #:: {
        val newOffset = offset + preWhitespace + word.length
        if (newOffset >= raw.length) Stream.empty
        else loop(newOffset)
      }
    }
    loop(0)
  }
```